# Modify the wrapping of the outer-most resource in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to modify the wrapping of the outer-most resource. In [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping) there is a solution on how to remove the default "data" wrap but I can't find how to change it to another key.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default via `Resource::withoutWrapping()`, and then manually wrap the data in the Resource class:

```
public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            "my-custom-key" => $this->resource->toArray()
        ];
    }
```